# jQuery - slide to the next p tag

Tags: jquery

So, I would like to have 2 buttons Next and Previous, which has to slide up or down in a text. Right now I got it to slide up and down 80px which is nice.

But I would like to know if it's possible to make it slide to the next p tag? And how would you do that?

My code is this right now:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
$('#contentText').animate({
    'top':'-=80px'
    });
});
//

$('#previous').click(function(){
$('#contentText').animate({
    'top':'+=80px'
    });
});
//
```

Comment: Can you post a live demo we can tweak?

Comment: Yes. But it seems like you already found an answer, so never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the jQuery scrollTo plugin.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Demo: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: That's just awesome! Thank you very much!